# Cant get POST data from request

Tags: php, post

I have and POST request look like this=

```
_csrf=4S-6CVNqdEl94k2sncvZIoH0YkUAov1bXc-HOukDap7zPixqpnmCaVwPWfSjP4f3h6xaEMiXUtMVJAP4NEzZGw%3D%3D
&LoginForm%5Bserver%5D=5
&LoginForm%5Busername%5D=login
&LoginForm%5Bpassword%5D=passwordROOT
```

Parsed its look like this:

```
_csrf: 4S-6CVNqdEl94k2sncvZIoH0YkUAov1bXc-HOukDap7zPixqpnmCaVwPWfSjP4f3h6xaEMiXUtMVJAP4NEzZGw==
LoginForm[server]: 5
LoginForm[username]: 444444
LoginForm[password]: 32222222222224234
```

And I have an PHP code, thats trying to get server, login and password from this request:

```php
<?
$login = $_POST['LoginForm[username]'];
$password = $_POST['LoginForm[password]'];
$server = $_POST['LoginForm[server]'];

echo $login;
echo $password;
echo $server;
?>
```

As result all of 'echo' is empty.

Comment: Try: `$_POST['LoginForm']['username'];`. If you pass something like: `foo[bar]`, `foo` will be an associative array with `bar` as a key.

Comment: And `print_r($_POST)` (this is __the first__ thing you should do)

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Thanks a lot! Its working

Comment: I would also recommend stop using the short open tag `<?` since it's been disabled as default since a bunch of PHP versions back. Use `<?php` instead. The short echo: `<?= $foo ?>` still works though. You should also check if `$_POST` contains the keys (like `LoginForm` etc) instead of assuming that you get the data you expect.